# Expect this.children.props()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme

i've to testing ErrorBoundry, i've this code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

 class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = { hasError: false }
  } 

 componentDidCatch (error, info) {
  this.setState({ hasError: true })
 }

 render () {
  if (this.state.hasError) {
   return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>
  }
  return this.props.children
 }
}

export default ErrorBoundary
```

and i want to testing, now i've test when there an error, and everythings it's ok, but how i can write on test file i expect return this.props.children() or simulate something similar?

i use enzyme

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this ? `.simulateError(error) => Self`
https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulateError.html

Comment: with Error everything it's ok, but now i don't know how test i get this.props.children when not have errors

Comment: so you can check if the children exist by searching.
`wrapper.find('div.element')`

Answer (score 0):

To test the non-error case just test that `ErrorBoundary` renders its children:

```
test('no error', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<ErrorBoundary><div>no error</div></ErrorBoundary>);
  expect(wrapper.html()).toBe('<div>no error</div>');  // Success!
});
```